# Microsoft Graph API Posts work in graph explorer 403 forbidden in postman

Tags: post, http-status-code-403, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm working on something that will create new messages in a MS Teams channel.  We have created a user account for this purpose and it's license properly.  When testing in postman I keep getting 403 errors when posting, while all Get requests work properly.  Posts in the Graph Explorer also work without any problems while logged in as this service user.

POST to https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{{teamid}}/channels/{{channelid}}/messages/

Body

```
{
  "messageType": "message",
  "subject": "test",
  "importance": "normal",
  "body": {
    "contentType": "text",
    "content": "testing with svc account"
  }
}
```

On graph explorer get a 201 back and the message shows up in Teams.

When I use postman I first obtain an access token, attempt a get to the same uri and get a good response back.  So the token has to be working, right?

Then try a post and get a 403.

Same user account.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide authentication.

MSDN actually has a page on using postman with the Graph API [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman).

Also to use the Graph API you need to create a [Application registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-register-app-v2) and depending on the API you use and how you log in, you may need to get the tenant to consent your application permissions.

Comment: I'll double check all that again, but I went through all those steps before including getting the app approve my MS.  I'll post again w/ my findings.

Comment: I've double checked permissions and as far as I can tell I've got the right set in there.  The application is registered and admin approved.  It's also been approved by MS for access to the graph api.  I'm trying to use delegated permissions for a service account.  The service account has access to Teams and is able to post messages w/o a problem via both the Teams web application and the MS Graph explorer.  The Application has ChannelMessage.Read.All, ChannelMessage.Send, Group.Read.All, TeamsActivity.Read, TeamsActivity.Send (as well as others that may or may not be applicable).

Comment: Are you using the 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' scope on authentication?  If you are then it's just making sure that the all the API's are consented correctly to the "delegated" type. You should be able to check them in the enterprise applications list on the tenant azure portal for your app registration with the admin consented page listed as delegated.

Comment: Another option is that you can specifically request a specific list of rights in the authentication 'scope' instead of the 'graph.microsoft.com/.default' scope.  If you don't have the rights then it will prompt for admin consent (like what graph explorer does if you ask for specific rights).

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Turns out we were missing Group.ReadWrite.All Delegated permission.  Only had the application level permission set.